# Copy an object according to a schema that may rename or drop properties

Tags: typescript, recursion

Using Typescript, I'm looking to build a function that turns an object like this into a new object according to a specific "schema object" which specifies ...

- which properties to keep (and which to omit)
- how to name that property when copying it

**Input Object**

```
{
  firstName: "Jane",
  lastName: "Miller",
  address: {
    street: "123 Fake Street",
    city: "Fake City",
  },
};
```

**Schema Object**

```
{
firstName: "MyFirstName",
address: {_self: "MyAddress", street: "MyStreet" }
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
MyFirstName: "Jane",
MyAddress: { 
 "MyStreet: "123 Fake Stret"
 }
}
```

Comment: objects can't have duplicate keys. How do you expect that schema object to work? are you going to pass it in as a string instead of an object?

Comment: My bad, I edited the question and renamed the key. I do want to pass in the schema as an object.

Comment: I would recommend using `Object.entries` to get all the key value pairs in the Schema object, then iterate, adding to a new object as you go along.`for all (k,v) if typeof v = object => recur, else newObject[v]= originalObject[k]` You will need to familiarize yourself with `keyOf` to overcome some errors you will face while implementing this pseudocode